# How to find repaired files by reading CBS.LOG

Tags: windows-10, sfc

I ran `sfc /scannow`

Get the message

> Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully
> repaired them. For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log
> file located at windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example
> C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline repairs, details are included
> in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.

Looking at the log file generated I couldn't really see anything that jumped out at me as a corrupt file.
But then again...the file is quit large `15,425 KB`.

What keyword exist that I can search on to find what files were corrupt?

Comment: Same. Sfc.exe says it repaired something, but there is nothing in my log file to indicate what was fixed. Windows 10 LTSC 2021 clean install. Repeatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has published instructions for this:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system

Open a elevated command prompt and run this command:

```
findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"
```

That creates the sfcdetails.txt on the desktop with the informationen.

If the information is no longer available in the current CBS log file, you must adapt the command to the previous log file that is in the specified folder.

Comment: Ok...from the article:  The file includes information about files that were not repaired by the System File Checker tool. I guess that would be really helpful...but in my case I was really curious as to what files were fixed. I did gleam from the doc that I should have run `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` first. I checked the log file for '[SR]" and it basically says
00000006 [SR] Verifying 1 components
00000007 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
00000008 [SR] Verify complete